# Is it possible to get user birthday and gender with google signIn in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-signin, mobile-application

Hello I am using flutter and I implemented correctly the google signIn but even by changing the scope I only get:
"Display name" 
"Email"
"Img url"

Here is the code to make the user log in:

```
GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
// Step 2
GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
  accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
  idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
);
print(googleAuth.toString());

final FirebaseUser user =
    (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;

// Step 3
updateUserData(user);

// Done

print("signed in " + user.displayName);
return user;


}



void updateUserData(FirebaseUser user) async {
    DocumentReference ref = _db.collection('users').document(user.uid);

return ref.setData({
  'uid': user.uid,
  'email': user.email,
  'photoURL': user.photoUrl,
  'displayName': user.displayName,
  'lastSeen': DateTime.now()
}, merge: true);


}
```

Comment: use web based google signin. and request dob from console

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, could you explain me more in detail what you mean ?

Comment: Can you show some code how do you get user entity?

Comment: I just edited the original post

Comment: I am using the google signIn package

Comment: Hope, this will help you:
[Get Date of Birth using google_signin flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59844578/get-users-birthday-gender-using-google-sign-in-in-flutter)