# Get user's birthday/gender using Google Sign-In in Flutter

Tags: authentication, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I want to get user's birthday and gender using Firebase Auth and Google Sign-In. Unfortunately, after the login happens, I am getting only the user's email, display name, photo url and phone number. I saw that I can add scopes to the GoogleSignIn object, which I do - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, but still, I don't see any additional data after the login. Any idea how to get the result of this? Because when these scopes are added to the object, it asks me if I accept to give this data before doing the login, so I guess there should be a way to fetch and display them.

Here is my login code:

```
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: ["email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"]);
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<FirebaseUser> _handleSignIn() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );

    final FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
    return user;
  }
```

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/google-apis

Answer (score 4):

I hope this becomes useful to anyone else facing the same trouble :)

```
 GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: ['email',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"]);
  
  @override
  Future<User> login() async {
    await googleSignIn.signIn();
    User user = new User(
      email: googleSignIn.currentUser.email,
      name: googleSignIn.currentUser.displayName,
      profilePicURL: googleSignIn.currentUser.photoUrl,
      gender: await getGender()
    );
     
    return user;
  }

  Future<String> getGender() async {
    final headers = await googleSignIn.currentUser.authHeaders;
    final r = await http.get("https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=genders&key=",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": headers["Authorization"]
      }
    );
    final response = JSON.jsonDecode(r.body);
    return response["genders"][0]["formattedValue"];
  }
```

Comment: You need to enable Google People API for your project first

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/google-apis

Comment: hello, how about getting the birthday??

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable [Google People API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/people.googleapis.com/overview)
2. Add [googleapis](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis) and [extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth) packages

```dart
import 'package:extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth/extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:googleapis/people/v1.dart';

// 1 add scopes
final googleSignin = GoogleSignIn(scopes: <String>[
  PeopleServiceApi.userBirthdayReadScope,
  PeopleServiceApi.userGenderReadScope,
]);

// 2 login with google

loginWithGoogle() async {
  await googleSignin.signIn();
}

// 3: fetch gender and birthday
_fetchGenderAndBirthday() async {
  var httpClient = (await googleSignin.authenticatedClient())!;

  var peopleApi = PeopleServiceApi(httpClient);

  final Person person = await peopleApi.people.get(
    'people/me',
    personFields:
        'birthdays,genders', // add more fields with comma separated and no space
  );

  /// Gender
  final String gender = person.genders![0].formattedValue!;

  /// Birthdate
  final date = person.birthdays![0].date!;
  final DateTime birthdayDateTime = DateTime(
    date.year ?? 0,
    date.month ?? 0,
    date.day ?? 0,
  );
}
```

to learn more about available scopes go to [People API documentation](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get)